# SQL Join from 2 Tables with Null Values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables and want to pull the results back from them into one.
Now the Name field is a unique ID with multiple data attached to it, i.e. the dates and the times. I've simplified the data somewhat to post here but this is the general gist.

Table 1

```
Name    Date
John    12th
John    13th
John    15th
John    17th
```

Table 2

```
Name    Colour
John    Red
John    Blue
John    Orange
John    Green
```

Result Needed

```
Name    Date    Time
John    12th    NULL
John    13th    NULL
John    15th    NULL
John    17th    NULL
John    NULL    Red
John    NULL    Blue
John    NULL    Orange
John    NULL    Green
```

I'm currently performing a Left join to pull the data however it is posting the results next to each other like

```
John 12th Red
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Show us the query you are using (**[Edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Your question and expected output doesn't make any sense to me, I think single table data represents as multiple table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `union all`:

```
select name, date, null as colour
from t1
union all
select name, null, colour
from t2;
```

I took the liberty of naming the second column `colour` rather than `time`, simply because that makes more sense in the context of the question.